# Optimize table to avoid using temporary and using filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a messages table

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `dest` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  KEY `dest` (`dest`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2758 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to get messages between two users

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `messages` m
LEFT JOIN `people` p ON m.author = p.id
WHERE
    (author = 1 AND dest = 2)
OR (author = 2 AND dest = 1)
ORDER BY
    m.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

When I EXPLAIN this query I get

[image]

Please excuse any ignorance, but is there a way I could optimize this table to avoid using a temporary table and filesort for this query, for now it is not causing a problem but I'm pretty sure in future it is going to be troublesome?

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm guessing the `left join` is not necessary.  Second, consider using `union all` instead.  Then one approach is:

```
(SELECT ...
 FROM messages m JOIN
      people p
      ON m.author = p.id
 WHERE author = 1 AND dest = 2
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 25
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ...
 FROM messages m JOIN
      people p
      ON m.author = p.id
 WHERE author = 2 AND dest = 1
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 25
)
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

With this query, an index on `messages(author, dest, id)` should make it fast.  (Note:  you might need to include `m.id` in the `SELECT` list.)

Comment: This way, running 2 queries and selecting 25 redundant records, will still be faster when the database grows in volume, right?

Comment: This appears as a very good answer but it actually broke my application, can you assist me further? First the problem was that it would only load up to 2 pages (50 records total) because of the limits in the sub queries, then I figured I could add pagination to these limits as well (0, 25, 50, 75 for pages 1, 2, 3, 4) but then I got some totally random results (well probably not random but it's how they seemed to me)

Comment: @php_nub_qq . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as another question.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, the reason this distorts your order is because Gordon is getting explicitly 25 from each user individually based on when each posted, not the most recent 25 between the two which are two totally different answers to what your original query was producing.  However, the index suggested of (author, dest, id) WILL still help the performance.

Answer (score 1):

To build on Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT  m2..., p...
    FROM
    ( 
      ( SELECT  id
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  author = 1
              AND  dest = 2
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  75 
      )
    UNION  ALL
      (
        SELECT  id
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  author = 2
              AND  dest = 1
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  75 
      )
    ) ORDER BY  id DESC
    LIMIT  50, 25 ) AS m1
    JOIN  messages AS m2  ON m2.id = m1.id
    JOIN  people p  ON p.id = m2.author
    ORDER BY  m1.id DESC
```

Notes:

- Gordon's index is now "covering".  (This adds efficiency, thereby masking some of the other stuff I added.)
- Lazy evaluation means that it does not need to shovel all the bulky fields of more than 25 rows around.  Instead, only 25 need to be handled.  Also, I avoid touching `people` to start with.
- The code shows what "page 3" should look like.  Note `LIMIT 75` versus `LIMIT 50,25`.
- "Pagination via `OFFSET`" has several problems.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).
- This formulation still will not avoid "filesort" and "using temp".  But speed is the real goal, correct?  ("Filesort" is a misnomer -- if you don't include that `TEXT` column, the sort will be done in RAM.)
- When you add `INDEX(author, dest, id)`, `INDEX(author)` becomes redundant; drop it.
- The `ALL` after `UNION` is not the default for `UNION`, but it avoids an extra pass (and temp table) to de-duplicate the data.
- There will still be 2 or 3 temp tables involved.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for details.

Comment: But, if I continue to increase pages I need to increase the value in the limits of the inner queries, this will increase the number of records in the derived table and at some point I can get like hundreds of thousand of records in there, is this not going to be a problem?

Comment: True, this gets slower and slower.  (Your original was slow always.)  Do users _really_ page through hundreds of pages?  Ponder having a different UI.  Such as encouraging the user to add a third criteria for filtering.  Maybe discover that there are "too many" entries and force the user to do more filtering.

Comment: I have another idea, what if I modify the `dest` column in such a way that instead of storing the receiver's id it stores a string containing both users' ids like `1_2` for example, then I could query using `WHERE dest = '<user1id>_<user2id>'` but I'm not sure how good string indexes work? Would you suggest this would be an acceptable thing to do? The lower id will always go first so there won't be a problem where `1_2` and `2_1` wouldn't return the same results.

Comment: Additionally, I am not quite sure about the reason for this but for now at about 15k records the syntax in the question is faster than both answers with a dramatic difference of `~0.015s` to `~0.1s`

Comment: The is no advantage in combining two columns into one (`1_2`).

Comment: If you have a _symmetric_ relationship (eg, where 2 people are siblings), it may be practical to sort the ids.  That is, have (1,2) and not (2,1).  (It did not seem like 'author' and 'dest' would be symmetric.)